# Implementing Objectify Entity relation

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I m new to GAE and datastore. I m trying Objectify-version 5, to access datastore. I m very confused about the way a relationship is maintained across Entity with Objectify. I cant map the idea of relational schema to Objectify framework, for basic understanding. In relational DB (like the PK/FK stuff),its much easier to get. I find it very difficult to understand the relations (1- many,many-many) with Objectify.I read the objectify doc [here](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Introduction), still no understanding, its not clear yet.For instance,I have an objectify Entity- Manager, another Entity- Employee. I want to maintain one-2-many relation between Manager-To-Employee. Questions are -

1. How do I put a reference (like Foreign key in RDBMS) of Manager Entity in Employee Entity.
2. After reference is set, how do I get all employees working for A Manager?
3. How do I implement many-2-many relation for those Entities .

Comment: Objectify doesn't change the way you manage entity relationships so you should probably read the Datastore [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities) to familiarise yourself with the concepts before reading about Objectify.  `1:n` or `n:n` relationships are typically implemented using indexed `Key` properties or `List<Key>` properties, depending on your requirements.

Comment: thnk u, can u give me an example of one-many entity persistence, I mean how do I get the Manager entity reference in the Employee entity while inserting an Employee working for him, assuming Manager:employee=One:Many.  Before persisting Employee entity, ofy().save().entity(emp).now(); how to get it a Manager reference. Thank u.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as stated [here](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Entities#Relationships):

> How do I put a reference (like Foreign key in RDBMS) of Manager Entity in Employee Entity.

use `Key<Manager>` or `Ref<Manager>` . They are basically interchangable but `Ref` holds a get method to fetch the entity if needed.

> After reference is set, how do I get all employees
>   working for A Manager?

If you are using your "foreign key" approach, you just need to query the datastore for Employee entities with the field "manager" equal to a ref or Key to the manager ID, like it was any other value.

> How do I implement many-2-many relation for those entities

You can store reference collections like `List<Key<Employee>>` or `Set<Ref<Manager>`

Comment: Thnk u, can u tell me how do I get the reference to Manager while inserting employee entity, like- Employee emp = new Employee();
employee.manager = Ref.create(managerKey);
ofy().save().entity(emp).now();  how to get that managerKey which was previously inserted. And what does this Ref.create ()  method do ?

Comment: Ref.create basically gives you a Ref Object containing the entity id and type which is all GAE needs to query. In order to get the key you only need the entity kind and id (just like a Ref), unfortunately you need to create a key to get the ref, but with a quick hack it should look something like this Ref.create(Key.create(Manager.class, managerId));

Comment: Thnk u so much bro, u made my day.Hope answer these- why do we need a Key for every entity, since we ALREADY have an auto-generated unique @Id (long,Long,string) field ? Does the key remain the same for the same entity reference ? Whats d use of Parent-Child relation ?

Comment: Hey Tanvir Key( or Ref) holds the Id+entity type+parent info. Why? because there are no "tables" in datastore and that's why you need to add that additional info for the entity, to know what it actually is. The @id generates a Key attribute . All of this is done by Objectify, they just hide the nasty details for you.

Comment: Parent-child relationships are used to make sure both entities are created in the same entity group, entity groups are a key concept in datastore, but the main thing you should know is that you cant access multiple entity groups in a single transaction. More info here: https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Concepts